# Hbase - Is it possible to create inputsplits for a mapreduce job based on column count of hbase row?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hbase

We have to run mapreduce job on a hbase table which has millions of rows and cells.

We know each region will be assigned with one mapper for processing. If we use a job to scan a table with 100 small regions, we need a job with 100 mappers. We found Small regions waste a lot of computing resources.  Large regions always block the job. For example if in a 100 region table, one region is far large then the other 99 regions. When we run a job with the table as input, 99 mappers will be completed very quickly, and then we need to wait for the last mapper for a long time.

In order to avoid this issue, we tried reducing dataskew on mapreduce inputsplits using the below properties.

'hbase.mapreduce.input.autobalance' and 'hbase.mapreduce.input.autobalance.maxskewratio'

This works well by splitting the large regions into multiple small regions of almost equal size.
[RegionSizeCalculator is internally used to calculate the size of each region.]

Run time for each split is given below(after setting autobalance to true).

[image]

From the above observation, we didn't find much variance in the size of input splits. But some of the splits are still taking more time for processing.

On further analysis we found the time taken for processing split is directly proportional to the number of cells present in the split. (refer above picture)

So is there any way to split the regions based on the column count in that particular regions instead of dividing it using spit length(used in autobalance).

Note: It takes more time if we do a full table scan for counting the cells in each row.

Comment: hi, have you solved this issue??

Comment: No. Still didn't find any solution.

Comment: ok, let me review it!! maybe i can help you with it

Comment: @KenrySanchez did you get a chance to go through this issue.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've been doing with a problem in my cluster the whole week. I promise I'll review this tomorrow.